# Calling a method multiple times when using h:dataTable in JSF

Tags: jsf

Can you guys help me to explain the reason why the method is called multiple times when I used the h:dataTable in facelet page.

```
 <h:dataTable id="listTable" styleClass="pageView_listForm"
 value="#{ClassName.dataFactory(topic)}" border="2" rules="rows" 
var="item" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="panelRowOdd,panelRowEven" >
        //Body
        </h:dataTable>
```

Bean class

```
@ManagedBean (name="ClassName")
@SessionScoped
public class ClassName{
   ...
     public DataModel <Person> dataFactory(String topic){
       DataModel items = null;  
       ..........
       // This block code gets the list of Person
       ..........
       return items;
    }

}
```

I was launching the page when it called the method dataFactory multiple times. I did not know exactly what happen here? Is it a bug from JSF or my implementation.Can you guy help me?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

when happens with Datatable, we should take care that such a method should not contain much business logic, Or Database interactions which are costly.

here i found some useful discussions....

[Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

[Why is BackingBean method called multiple times when requesting facelet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272289/why-is-backingbean-method-called-multiple-times-when-requesting-facelet)

[This](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/49982/jsf-2-0-datatable-reload-again-and-again)

and [`here`](http://seamframework.org/Community/HowtoAvoidMethodOrGetterToBeCalledSeveralTimesByCachingResult)

[Calling a method multiple times when using h:dataTable in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609067/calling-a-method-multiple-times-when-using-hdatatable-in-jsf)

Comment: I guess that I can find the solution to fix this issue by working around. Thanks